# When I install Bigcommerce npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli I get this error

Tags: command-line-interface, bigcommerce

[image: I get this error]

When I run this npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli I get this error. When I try the above code in cmd, it throws an error Please find the below error screen.

How can i fix this issue please let me know if you understand this issue :)

Comment: Unable to view the image containing the error. Please include the error message directly in your question.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It tells you the issue at the very top. You are using Node 20, but Stencil must be installed using Node 18. Please switch your Node version to 18 and try again.